# Maclane/Birkhoff's "Algebra" as a first book on the subject?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Would the more knowledgeable and well-versed members of this community be so helpful as to give their opinion on using Birkhoff & MacLane's famous "Algebra" for a first course in Abstract Algebra? Would it be a good introduction to the subject? Would it be suitable for self-study?

Obviously, the answers are bound to be highly personal. But knowing what others have to say sure makes it easier to commit to a book (and, by extension, the price tag attached to said book). Especially considering Herstein, Dummitt & Foote, Artin and others are considerably more expensive.

Comment: Do you mean  "Algebra" by MacLane and Birkhoff or "A Survey of Modern Algebra" by Birkhoff and MacLane? Note the order of the authors.

Comment: Like I said, "Algebra", not "A Survey of Modern Algebra".

Comment: If you are looking for strengthening your intuition, please look into Gallian's book "Contemporary Abstract Algebra". He gives a lot of examples. Before giving a definition, he puts in the right motivation. Also after proving a theorem he gives unexpected applications to groups which you might not have imagined possible. The style in which the book is written is like a story.  Herstein is a classic, but it's pretty old. I would recommend Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @BijeshK.S Lovely book, but for the grand total price of $200 I can get myself Herstein (or Artin). I was looking at MacLane/Birkhoff seeing as its a lot more affordable.

Comment: That's unfortunate, here in India, I bought it for $300$rs, nearly $5$ US dollars.

Answer (score 4):

"Algebra" by MacLane and Birkhoff was the first abstract algebra book I bought and I loved it!

It wasn't the first abstract algebra book I read, though, but it probably was the first book that I read carefully.

I recommend "Algebra" for self study at your leisure.
It will teach you undergraduate abstract algebra while introducing you to categorical ideas, especially the role of universals. Highly recommended.

It could probably work for teaching a first course to students who have never seen abstract algebra, if the instructor is at ease with it.

Comment: Wonderful, this way I can get a number of answers and draw my conclusions from there! Just a few questions though: 1) Do you consider this book enough to build the often sought-after 'abstract algebraic intuition'? 2) How does this book compare to others in my original post, assuming you have some experience with a few of the authors? 3) Is the book too terse to give a "greater picture"-feel for algebra and how its topics tie in together?

Answer (score 1):

I am definitely not well-versed or knowledgeable on the subject. I have however tried to read many algebra books. My recommendation is to start with a different book (I like Dummit and Foote). Preferably one that does not use category theory, unless you are a genius this will probably save you from a lot of suffering.

Comment: +1. Or maybe start with a more "easier" text like Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra or Fraleigh's algebra book. Both are excellent in theory and have a good collection of problems.